# XAML Master / Template pages with MVVM

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp

Is there a way to create master / template pages in XAML (for UWP applications)?

The problem I'm trying to solve:
I have an application with a lot of similar sites, where only the content changes slightly but not the Buttons and the Layout. Example:

```
<Page
    DataContext="{Binding WebpageViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Edit Webpage" Style="{StaticResource BigTexBlock}" />
            <ScrollViewer  Style="{StaticResource ContentScrollViewer}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
                <StackPanel Margin="10,0">
                    <webpage:EditWebpage DataContext="{Binding }" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
                <!-- more buttons -->
                <AppBarButton IsCompact="True" Command="{Binding SaveEntryCommand}" Icon="Save" Label="Save" />
            </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
</Page>
```

Only three parts of this template will change; the ViewModel in the `DataContext`, the Text of the `TextBlock`, and the `UserControl` which contains the editable fields.

As this is an application with a lot of CRUD happening with simple Entities the amount of code to be repeated over and over again is a lot if I keep "solving" the problem like this. In the separated business logic I could avoid this problem with inheritance, but I'm struggling to find a elegant solution in XAML.

Is there a way to refactor this so I may have a "Template Page"?
I like how for example twig has solved this problem: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/. You define a master/template page and override parts of it in the children templates.

Important to me is that

- I don't break the MVVM pattern.
- I don't want to hide/show UserControls in one "Main" XAML as the amount of different entities may become quite large
- I want navigation happening between the pages that the user sees the expected animations, and it does not break the separated view code I already have

Comment: There is a [MasterDetailsView control](http://docs.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/MasterDetailsView/) control in UWP Community Toolkit. Maybe it could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem with the approach suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/43170663

my NavigationService

```
//get the current frame
var frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
//navigate to the generic AddEntry page
frame.Navigate(typeof(AddEntryPage), new NavigationParameter() { /* set props needed */ });
```

my xaml (my "master page") looks now like this (using a `Frame` now):

```
<Page
    x:Class="Famoser.Bookmarked.Presentation.Universal.Pages.Entry.Webpage.AddEntryPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{Binding WebpageViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Title" Grid.Row="0" Text="Add "/>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
            <StackPanel Margin="10,0">
                <Frame x:Name="EntryFrame" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
                <!-- more app buttons -->
                <AppBarButton IsCompact="True" Command="{Binding SaveEntryCommand}" Icon="Save" Label="Save" />
            </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
</Page>
```

and in the code behind in the navigation event I set the properties passed by my NavigationService

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if (e.Parameter is NavigationParameter pm)
    {
        DataContext = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance(pm.ViewModelType);
        Title.Text = "Add " + pm.Name;
        EntryFrame.Navigate(pm.EditFrameType);
    }
}
```

the full project in on github: https://github.com/famoser/Bookmarked

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a master page or template mechanism that other technologies, like MVC, have. But you can use frames and navigation to do what you're looking for.

You could keep the page defined the way you currently have it. All of the fixed elements on the page are in the layout. Now instead of using a UserControl for your specific edit UI, replace that with a frame.

```
<StackPanel Margin="10,0">
    <Frame Name="EditFrame" DataContext="{Binding }" />
</StackPanel>
```

Now when you navigate to the Main Edit page, also pass the type for the view you want in the frame. Then on your OnNavigatedTo override for the main page, you can navigate the frame to the view type as the parameter.

You can also use the EditFrame to page through multiple editing pages, like if you had a wizard UI with Next and Previous buttons, without leaving the main page.

You can either do this in your OnNavigatedTo method or modify your NavigationService to be able to handle this behavior.

Comment: I initially wanted to avoid to have code behind the XAML pages, but as it seems like there is no other way I'll probably will end up doing something similar to what you've proposed. Thanks for the tip with the `OnNavigatedTo`

Comment: You don't necessarily need to do it in the code behind. What MVVM library/framework are you using? There are ways to do it by extending the NavigationService for your app. Do you have one?

Comment: Im using the `MVVM light` library, with a custom implementation of the `INavigationService`. With code behind I meant the overriding of the `OnNavigatedTo` method, I'm just used to have a single page per ViewModel, and no code at all in my pages

Comment: If that's the case, you can extend your custom NavigationService to allow you to pass the target frame (by Name) as well as the page you're navigating to. Then the NavigationService can find the frame and call its Navigate method to the specific edit subpage. Does that make sense?  Then you don't have to have code in your code behind file.

Comment: I've solved the problem with the approach you suggested, thanks! I've used the `OnNavigatedEvent` to keep some complexity out of the `NavigationService` (I have multiple template pages)